# Summon Greater Demon: Can I summon a specific demon for which I know the true name?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The Summon Greater Demon spell is especially effective when the summoned demon's true name is known:

> At the end of each of the demon’s turns, it makes a Charisma saving throw. The demon has disadvantage on this saving throw if you say its true name.

However, the spell description doesn't say that it is possible to request a specific demon for which the true name is known:

> You utter foul words, summoning one demon from the chaos of the Abyss. You choose the demon’s type, which must be one of challenge rating 5 or lower, such as a shadow demon or a barlgura.

Is it possible to request a demon for which the true name is known?

Comment: Follow up to [Summon Greater Demon: Can I order the demon to tell me its true name](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/183949/summon-greater-demon-can-i-order-the-demon-to-tell-me-its-true-name)

Comment: The question [What creatures can you summon with summon greater demon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/180154/what-creatures-can-you-summon-with-summon-greater-demon) asks what type of creatures can be summoned, not if a particular individual can be selected.

Comment: This is in my opinion not a duplicate of [I have a demon's true name. Now what?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/137721/i-have-a-demons-true-name-now-what), which focuses on what to do when the demon is already summoned on the material plane: "**What can a player do with a demon's true name, particularly if the demon is already on the Material Plane?**"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No

You've answered your own question:

> the spell description doesn't say that it is possible to request a specific demon for which the true name is known

If it were possible, it would be specified in the spell. The spell, however, only specifies that:

> You choose the demon’s type...

If you could summon a specific demon, this would be explained in the spell's description. Since it isn't listed as a possibility in the spell's description, it's outside of what the spell can do.

Comment: The MM (pg. 53) hints that summoning a specific demon might be possible: "A mortal who learns a demon’s true name can use powerful summoning magic to call the demon from the Abyss and exercise some measure of control over it."

Comment: @GuillaumeF. The _gate_ spell can summon a specific named demon.